# Pygame download and installation error

Tags: python3

I tried to install Pygame into my Ubuntu laptop.
I opened the terminal and enetered :
    `sudo apt-get install python-pygame` 
Then after completing all the formalities I tried to use pygame in my python IDLE by typing: 
    `import pygame` . 
But the Idle says that there is no module called pygame. I searched for answers and tried a lot of them but I didnt find an answer. Can anyone please help !...

Comment: You have installed `pygame` for Python 2 and not Python 3. Did you install IDLE for Python 2 or for Python 3?

Comment: Yes . In fact I have two IDLE's working on my laptop right now. One works with python2 and python3

Comment: Why don't you try invoking IDLE by running `idle` in your terminal and then try `import pygame`?

Answer (score 0):

Fire up a terminal and run:

```
/usr/bin/python2
import pygame
```

If it doesn't give you any errors, you're good to go! You can then exit the interpreter with: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>

If it worked fine, that probably means you installed a custom version of Python that doesn't see the modules installed by `apt-get`.

Comment: It is not true that Python 3 is default; Python 2 is default.

Comment: @edwinksl - Updated. The source I read must have been wrong.

Comment: so what do i do right now??

Answer (score 0):

You might need to get pygame for Python 3
To do this first install pip to install Python packages...

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

Then install pygame...

```
python3 -m pip install pygame
```

That should be it :-)